# how to start looking into the java project?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I have recently join a team in an organization. they have assign me a project. now I have the project source code build in GWT and Java. I have imported the project in my eclipse. Now I can not figure out how to start looking into it as it contains so many packages and java files.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should understand what your code does in terms of business cases, and then high-level analyze it, without spending tons of time trying to figure out why each line of code is written, and when you will get it, life will become easier